# Yii CGridView button - call parametrized javascript function

Tags: php, javascript, yii, cgridview, cbuttoncolumn

I need to create a CGridView with one button and make the button call javascript function like this:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'projectCities',
    'summaryText' => '',
    'dataProvider' => $model->getCitiesProvider(),
    'columns' => array(
        'name',
        'directional',
        'customCount',
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            'template'=>'{delete}',
            'buttons' => array(
                'delete' => array(
                    'url' => '',
                    'click' => '',
                    'options' => array(
                        'onclick' => 'removeCity(this, $data->idCity, 
                                      $model->idProject); return false;',
                    ),                          
                )
            ),
        )
    ),
    ));
```

Ofcourse it's not working, because the generated html is:

```
<a class="delete" title="Delete" onclick="removeCity(this, $data->idCity, $model->idProject); return false;">
```

Is there a way to do it so there will be proper id in the javascript function call?

Answer (score 2):

```
//Controller:
public function gridButtons($model)
{   
    return array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{delete}',
        'buttons' => array(
            'delete' => array(
                'url' => '',
                'click' => '',
                'options' => array(
                    'onclick' => sprintf(
                        'js:removeCity(this, %d, %d);return false;',
                        $model->idCity, $model->idProject
                    ),
                ),                          
            )
        ),
    )
}
//view
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'projectCities',
    'summaryText' => '',
    'dataProvider' => $model->getCitiesProvider(),
    'columns' => array(
        'name',
        'directional',
        'customCount',
        array(            
            'value' => array($this, 'gridButtons'),            
        ),        
    ),
));
```

Comment: You cannot define `'data-city-id' => $data->idCity` - it will show you error `Undefined variable: data`

Comment: Good work. It is pretty close I guess. I have the problem with `$model->idProject`. I guess it's because Cities and Projects tables are related with `many-to-many` relationship. So I'm getting `Property "Cities.idProject" is not defined.`. I tried to access the table using ORM: `$model->projects->idProject` but I got `Trying to get property of non-object ` error. That is weird - if there was no project assigned to the city - it wouldn't appear.

Comment: `$model->projects` is array. Inside `gridButtons` check if empty `$model->projects` and is not you can access it `$model->projects[0]->id`

Comment: I tried that to, but it says `htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given `

Answer (score 0):

You can use double quotes to activate variable replacement in your string:

```
'onclick' => "js:removeCity(this, {$data->idCity}, {$model->idProject}); return false;",
```

Comment: It will result in syntax error - you cannot do sth like `${data->idCity}` (`->` will be unexpected).

Comment: @Joe: That's not true. Please read the section "Complex (curly) syntax" on this page: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php. EDIT: Fixed the typo: the `$` must be inside the `{}`.

Comment: I agree you won't get syntax error when move `$` in between `{}` but then - you will get `Undefined variable: data` error. I checked it :)

Comment: Oh, right. The variables are only availabel for some of the properties, mainly the URL related.

Answer (score 0):

I facing this problem and also solve this.May be your problem is going to 'option' array close after 'click' parameter where js function have staying.But 'option' array close before 'click' parameter below this way.Please see this,may be this solve problem are help to you.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'projectCities',
'summaryText' => '',
'dataProvider' => $model->getCitiesProvider(),
'columns' => array(
    'name',
    'directional',
    'customCount',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template'=>'{delete}',
        'buttons' => array(
            'delete' => array(                      
       'url'=>'$data->id',
       'visible'=>'true',
       'options'=>array('class'=>'viewbtns'),
       'click'=>'js: function(){ viewProfile((this).attr("href"),"openDialog" ); return false; }',

            )
        ),
    )
),
));
```